# Der/die/das as pronoun?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

> And was it easier for those from the Indian School?
>
> (Attempted translation: Und war es einfacher fuer die aus der Indische Schule?

This is the translation which came to me. Is it correct? If so, how exactly is "die" being used here.. am a little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronoun is fine, you got the adjectival declension wrong though: "aus der indische**n** Schule" (and "indischen" should only be capitalized if "Indische Schule" is a proper name, which I do not think it is).

Comment: So "die" is being used as a pronoun?

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller yes, all definite articles can be used like that https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/die#Pronomen